# Reopening Chronicle Map gives checksum errors

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

Using Chronicle Map version 3.20.84
When reopening an Chronicle Map I get the following:

```
map.ChronicleMapBuilder - Checksum doesn't match, stored: -1805860448, should be from the entry bytes: 1297789250, key: 4-US9024941034, value:...
```

I have seen https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/issues/198 which seems to exhibit the same problem I am having.

Over there is says to make sure you don't write to the map after it is closed. As of release 3.x of ChronicleMap I discovered that there is a shutdown hook mechanism that closes the maps for you. I turned that feature off. Since shutdown hooks are called arbitrarily I reasoned that I may have been still been writing to the map after the hook closed it down. Instead I know close the maps myself. Yet I still am getting checksum errors when trying to reopen previously closed maps.

Any idea what is going?

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown hooks should only be called by the JVM after all your threads have been killed.

I would check you aren't killing your process with `kill -9`

I would try a newer version, as this version 2.5 years old, though I don't know of a fix for this in that time.

What sort of filesystem is the map stored on?

Comment: We have already ensured that we are not doing kill -9. That is not the issue.

Comment: @peter_lawrey, Could there be a thread-safety issue if more than one process is writing to the map. Aren't they supposed to be thread-safe?